# How to change the control task flow based on the task status?

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package. I have set several Handlers for different behaviors for the tasks.
My question is: One task in particular, if it fails, I want it to skip a few other tasks and jump ahead. 
So, I'd like to set the OnError for that particular task so it jumps to some other task.
How can I say the SSIS, inside the handler, to move ahead to a specific task?

I want to jump to another task in the control flow.

Comment: within the whole package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant say that to SSIS, you must implement it with precedence constraints.
Example: lets say you have tasks A -> B -> C -> D and you don't want C to execute if B fails, you can do this:

be aware the dotted lines, you need to set the precedence to OR otherwise D would only execute if B both succeeds and fail, which is not possible

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Control flow tasks on SSIS package execute based on the flow described in the package. Let's assume you have two tasks, a `Script Task` and a `Data flow task`. Both the tasks here are connected to each other. Script task is purposefully coded to fail. When it does, the package will stop execution at that point because it is structured to execute the Data Flow Task only on the successful execution of the Script Task.

[image: failure]

You can right click on the connector/precedence constraint between Script Task and Data Flow task and change it from `Success` to `Completion`. This would mean that it instructs the package to execute the `Data Flow Task` on completion of Script Task irrespective of whether it fails or succeeds.

[image: right-click on constraint]

Now, if you run the package, it will execute the data flow task even if the script task fails.

[image: completion]

You can also have multiple flows like this. All you have to do is right-click on the connector/precedence constraint between the tasks and choose the correct status to decide which path the package should execute.

[image: multiple flows]

Hope that helps.